# What do the numbers mean in the function range(len(sequence)-1,0,-1) mean?

Tags: python

I am currently being tasked with writing the bubble sort algorithm in python and one of the solutions I have come across contains this piece of code.

```
for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
            temp = alist[i]
            alist[i] = alist[i+1]
            alist[i+1] = temp
```

In line 1 the range is specified with -1,0,-1 and I don't know why or what this does and was wondering if anyone could help out? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation for the `range()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(len(alist)-1,0,-1)` returns a range of integers starting at `len(alist) - 1`, continuing utill it hits `0`, and increasing by `-1` (decreasing by 1) each iteration.

The first `for` loop is using this `range` statement to start at the end of `alist` (index `len(alist) -1`) and work backwards to the start (index `0`), one item at a time. The second `for` loop is starting at `0` and counting up to `passnum` - your code is checking the entire list first, then everything but the last element of the list, then everything but the second-to-last, and so on.

This implementation of Bubblesort is pushing the largest element to the end of the array - since we know the largest one will be at the end after each pass of the first `for` loop, there's no need to compare the next element to be sorted to the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

would like to add some more informations to above answers from the python documentation

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

range(stop)
range(start, stop[, step])
Rather than being a function, range is actually an immutable sequence type, as documented in Ranges and Sequence Types — list, tuple, range.

Example:

```
>>> list(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(range(1, 11))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list(range(0, 30, 5))
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
>>> list(range(0, 10, 3))
[0, 3, 6, 9]
>>> list(range(0, -10, -1))
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
>>> list(range(0))
[]
>>> list(range(1, 0))
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

if len(alist) = 10

`range(len(alist)-1,0)`
would mean []

`range(len(alist)-1,0,-1)`
the -1 indicated you subtract(-1) from len(alist)-1 till it reached 1, which would mean  the sequence will be [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]